# Create a dataframe with columns of given Date and Time

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to create a dataframe with its first column as `Date` and second column as `Time`. The condition is the time should increase in 30 minutes interval and the date accordingly. And later i will add other columns manually.

```
> df
Date          Time
2012-01-01    00:00:00
2012-01-01    00:30:00
2012-01-01    01:00:00
2012-01-01    01:30:00
..........    ........
..........    ........
and so on...
```

**EDIT**

Can be done in another way as well.

A single column can be created with the given date and time and then separated later using `tidyr` or any other packages.

```
> df
DateTime
2012-01-01 00:00:00
2012-01-01 00:30:00
2012-01-01 01:00:00
2012-01-01 01:30:00
.......... 
.......... 
and so on...
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you intend to use the date and time?  You might be better of just having a single date column, and then _presenting_ the separate date and time components as needed.

Comment: Yes, that can be done too. I really need help on doing this as well.

Comment: `dates_seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2012-02-01"), by=(30))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can generate a sequence using `seq`, specifying the start and end dates, and the time interval

```
df <- data.frame(DateTime = seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"),
                                as.POSIXct("2012-02-01"), 
                                by=(30*60)))
head(df)
             DateTime
1 2012-01-01 00:00:00
2 2012-01-01 00:30:00
3 2012-01-01 01:00:00
4 2012-01-01 01:30:00
5 2012-01-01 02:00:00
6 2012-01-01 02:30:00
```

And to get them in two separate columns we can use `?strftime`

```
date_seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), 
                as.POSIXct("2012-02-01"), 
                by=(30*60))

df <- data.frame(Date = strftime(date_seq, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                 Time = strftime(date_seq, format="%H:%M:%S"))

        Date     Time
1 2012-01-01 00:00:00
2 2012-01-01 00:00:30
3 2012-01-01 00:01:00
4 2012-01-01 00:01:30
5 2012-01-01 00:02:00
6 2012-01-01 00:02:30
```

---

**Update**

You can include the `time` part of the `POSIXct` datetime too. This will give you finer control over your upper & lower bounds:

```
date_seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01 00:00:00"), 
                as.POSIXct("2012-02-02 23:30:00"), 
                by=(30*60))

df <- data.frame(Date = strftime(date_seq, format="%Y-%m-%d"),
                 Time = strftime(date_seq, format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: with the code only the first time stamp is coming for the last date.

Comment: with the code only the first time stamp is coming for the last date.

Comment: @ShretaGhimire - change the `to` date to be the next day?

Comment: @ShretaGhimire - Please see my update. You can also specify the time part of the date too.